# Mock Database connections in haskell

Tags: haskell, hunit

I am trying to write some simple code in haskell where there is a function performs a simple database query. In order to unit test Iam using HUnit but not sure how I can mock the database connection and query response.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function that performs the database query as a parameter to your code, instead of having it "hardwired". During tests, pass a mock function to the code. In production, pass a function that really performs the database query.

This new function parameter should be at the right level of abstraction. For example, something like

```
queryDbForClient :: Connection -> SQLString -> ClientId -> IO (Maybe RowData)
```

is possibly a bad idea, because it still forces the code under test to be aware that things like `Connection`s and SQL strings exist. Something like this

```
findClientById :: ClientId -> IO (Maybe Client)
```

would likely be better, because then you are free to pass functions that don't use db-specific `Connection` types at all. They could, for example, be backed by an [in-memory reference](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html).

Notice that you can build `findClientById` out of `queryDbForClient` by partial application and mapping the result a little. But this should be the task of some *setup* code, not of the main code that you want to test.

---

Once you start passing functions in this way for the sake of testability and configurability, some common issues start to appear. For example, what if I have multiple dependencies? Passing them all as positional parameters is a chore. This might lead to passing them together in a record-of-functions, perhaps using [`Has`-like](https://hackernoon.com/the-has-type-class-pattern-ca12adab70ae) typeclasses so as not to tie your main code to any particular record.